Solving inverse trigonometric equation involving arccotangent.
$\tan^{-1}(x+1)+\cot^{-1}(\frac{1}{x-1})=\tan^{-1}(\frac{8}{31})$
One thing to clear is that the range of arccotangent is $(0,\pi)$. I am so sad because I can't use Wolfram to cross check my answers.
I tried to solve the problem and got two values of $x=\frac{1}{4},-8$ But I had used the tangent function on both sides. So there were high chances that extraneous roots have been generated. So I tried to put $x=\frac{1}{4}$ and  $-8$. But in both cases I came to the end value $\pi+\tan^{-1}(\frac{8}{31})$ which is not equal to $\tan^{-1}(\frac{8}{31})$
Moreover to my surprise both the answer are given as the correct answers in the answer key. I don't trust it though.
Please guide me where I am going wrong.
The issue is the arccotangent's range. Or it would have been way easier.
Edit 1: My solution:

Edit 2: Check if x= 1/4 is valid or not


Wolfram gives the answer as $\frac{1}{4}$ only. I will post a longer answer if anything comes to me.

@RedFive Ya I saw that sir...

Let's see what I could come upto with the range $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$....just solving to see if my answers match with wolfram's. However the original question is with the range mentioned in the question only.

All good - it is a nice problem. I am wondering if a sketch of a triangle may help somehow. Will post it as an answer if I get anywhere.

Sure sir @RedFive Eagerly waiting for your solution :)

No promises... I'll see what can be done though. I'm guessing the two answers you found came from forming and solving a quadratic in x?

Yes sir @RedFive

Wolfram is not showing the answer -8 because it doesn't satisfies the equation if we take the range of arccotangent from -pi/2 to pi/2

However the original ques was and is concerned with arccotangent range from 0 to pi, which indeed justifies the issue I mentioned in my ques (that extra +pi)

afaik, Wolfram alpha takes the range of arccot from 0 to pi

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad No Sir it treats arccot as a odd function which isn't possible on 0 to pi

@DarshitSharma I guess you're right...i plugged arccot(-root3) in Wolfram and it gave -pi/6....let me solve it...maybe then 1/4 won't come as an answer according to the domain of 0 to pi

@DarshitSharma i solved it...and guess what...-8 is a solution and 1/4 isn't

Personally, I would have approached the problem very differently, by working exclusively with arctan, and dispensing with any need to consider arccot.  This is easily done by considering the two separate cases of $~(x - 1) > 0,~$ and $~(x - 1) < 0.~$  When $~(x - 1) > 0,~$ you have that $$\text{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) = \text{arctan}(x-1).$$  When $~(x - 1) < 0,~$ you have that $$\text{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)= \text{arctan}(x-1) + \pi.$$

Wolfram spits out $x=\frac14$ because it treats the LHS like$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x2-\frac1x\right)+\frac\pi2\operatorname{sgn}(x)$$whereas, using your definition of $\cot^{-1}$, I think it should end up equivalent to$$\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x2-\frac1x\right)+\frac{3\pi}2&x>0\\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x2-\frac1x\right)+\frac\pi2&x<0\end{cases}$$

@user170231 Yeah sir, I have solved using both definitions, if we use mine x= -8 and if we use wolfram's x=1/4

This is not a full answer. I'll post the full fledged one if OP wishes. Kinda similar to the existing one tho.
First solve for the case when $x>1$
Then solve when $x\le-1$
And finally when $-1\le x<1$

When $x>1$
We have, $$\arctan(x+1)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{8}{31}\right)$$
$$\implies \arctan(x+1)+\arctan(x-1)=\arctan\frac{8}{31}$$
Solving this gives $x=\frac14$ or $x=-8$ but we must have $x>1$ so none of them are valid.

When $x<-1$
Let $x=-k$ where $k$ is a positive real number greater than $1$. Rewrite the equation as $$\arctan(1-k)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{-k-1}\right)=\arctan\frac{8}{31}$$ $$\implies -\arctan(k-1)+\pi-\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\arctan\frac{8}{31}$$ $$\implies \pi-\arctan\frac{8}{31}=\arctan(k+1)+\arctan(k-1)$$ We now have all arguments positive so we can apply the basic formula here.
After solving we get $k=8$ as solution or $x=-8$
Since $x$ must be $<-1$, this is a valid solution.
Hence the solution of this equation is $$\boxed{x=-8}$$

I leave it to the OP to solve for the left case.

Okay sir I'll try making cases. But please show me how x = 1/4 is a solution. Like please plug it in and prove LHS = RHS. I don't know why but when I do it that pi comes in between.

Please post a full fledged ans sir. I think your last case got subcases.

Oh yeah I too did it myself sir...-8 is the only possible answer to this equation.

@DarshitSharma that's good
